# Cross-platform document scanner functionality in Xamarin Forms App

Tags: forms, xamarin, document

As part of an Cross-platform App (Xamarin Forms) I'm developing I want a functionality that allows the user to scan a document.

Are for Xamarin Forms App components (libraries) available that can be used?

I know, [Scanbot Xamarin Document Scanner SDK](https://scanbot.io/developer/xamarin-document-scanner/) can be used for this, but that is quite expensive. Are there no alternatives available?

What's the best way to implement such a functionality with a limited amount of invested resourcers?

Comment: maybe you could look at [pixelnetica](https://www.pixelnetica.com/products/document-scanning-sdk/xamarin-document-scanner-sdk.html)

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT That's for X.IOS and X.Android, not for Xamarin Forms

Comment: you could use in Android or ios and then call in forms by DependencyService

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Do you have any alternaties for Xamarin.Android/IOS. I have switched from Forms to Xamarin Android/IOS, but unfortunately, you don't have much for that either..

Comment: @E75, did you find a scanning library for the Xamarin Forms. Pixelnetica doesn't have a camera UI while scanbot is very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I found this FREE solution:
[Imaging-Library](https://github.com/enginkirmaci/Imaging-Library)

It takes a photo file, finds the "square" (document) and crops out anything outside it.

You can use [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) to capture a photo or use an existing one that's on the phone.

I've tested and it works, but I think my photo quality was too high, as rendering took forever. You can tailor it to your needs.

Comment: MediaPlugin takes a picture, Imaging-Library is for cropping the photo. I assume you are talking about Imaging-Library taking too long. I had the same experience. I couldn't find any other solution, so maybe it's worth getting the source code of Imaging-Library and improve it? If you will find a suited solution, do share it please.

Comment: did you try pixelnetica ?

Comment: nope, this was a very long time ago too. If you will try, you may want to post a separate answer.