# Xamarin.Forms Document Scanner

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I scan the document with camera and write in to stream. Now is the hardest part, i need to write code for Cropping & Perspective Correction on the document taken. There is a nuget packages and libraries but they are expensive. I want to try to make my own code but don't know from where to start.
This is my code :

```
var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions() {
                  Directory = "Sample",
                  Name = "test.jpg",
                  SaveToAlbum = false,
              });

if (file == null)
    return;         

Stream stream = file.GetStream();
var localPath = string.Empty;

localPath = Task.Run(() => DependencyService.Get<Shared.ISharedFunction>().SaveFileToDisk(stream, "picture.jpg")).Result;
ImageDoc = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
Picture.Name = localPath;
ImagesNew.Add(Picture);
```

This is my code i'm using media library to take photo(document) , and saving in stream. Now for the stream i need to convert in pdf(it may be more then one image). I need Cropping & Perspective Correction on the image.

Comment: This question is way to broad to be answered here (at least in a way that is satisfying for all involved parties). Maybe you could take [this paper on image correction](https://cdn.iiit.ac.in/cdn/cvit.iiit.ac.in/images/ConferencePapers/2005/jagannathan05Perspective.pdf) as a starting point. Feel free to ask another question when you have a **specific** problem.

Comment: *Hint:* You'll somehow have to obtain the Pixels from the `stream` and rectify them by projecting the generic tetragon to a rectangle.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13404/mapping-irregular-quadrilateral-to-a-rectangle) helps

Comment: [See here](http://docs-hoffmann.de/persprect13052005.pdf), too

Comment: Thank u i will look at it

Comment: Maybe this answer helps i cant find something about the problem

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56950144/cross-platform-document-scanner-functionality-in-xamarin-forms-app) may help.